# restrict the "textfield" to accept only digits and maximum 10 digits in magento form

Tags: javascript, forms, magento, contacts

here is a code : http://pastebin.com/qCNGSKRn to display telephone filed to enter telephone number.

i want to restrict above field to accept only numbers and also maximum 10 numbers to be entered. all special charactars and special symbols and white spaces should not allowed.

that field should not accept more than 10 digits.

please help me to find solution.

```
<div class="field">
                <label for="telephone" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Telephone') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input type="text" name="telephone" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getTelephone()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Telephone') ?>" class="input-text  <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('telephone') ?>" id="telephone" />
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: The field is already being validated by `<?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('telephone') ?>`, defined in the input's `class=""`.  Customer's won't be able to enter anything other than a phone number.

Comment: thanks axel for reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have to use this in class " class="input-text validate-length maximum-length-10 minimum-length-10 validate-digits helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('telephone') ?>"" https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/56413/restrict-the-textfield-to-accept-only-digits-and-maximum-10-digits-in-magento

http://inchoo.net/magento/out-of-the-box-form-validation-in-magento/